# Professional Web Development Video Tutorials

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to learn Web development by watching Youtube videos and using w3schools.com, my question is that can anyone recommend any HTML5, CSS, Javascript video tutorials made by professionals please? any response will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are *a lot* of videos out there made by professionals, including the online courses

Comment: This is not a question for stack overflow.

Comment: this is a good one, however you should remove the question. http://www.lynda.com/

Comment: Please read the following articles to see what kind of questions to ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I read  Help Center > Asking  page and I understand that my question is off-topic, sorry about that, so what do I need to do now, shall I remove the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/html5-css3-fundamentals-development-for-absolute-beginners) provides professional videos from industry experts in a whole range of fields including web development. You'll need to sign up for a free account but that only takes a few minutes.

Comment: thanks for sharing this link, i hope more people like you come here and eventually change this community from to something normal.

Comment: The question is broad so I understand the community having a problem with it but I think there are useful answers out there so it should be left up. Hopefully I've helped someone :)